# using reverse on a self-defined list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I did a self-defined data type called Queue and trying to enqueue Integers at the end of the "list".

```
data Queue = Ele Int Queue | Nil

-- [..] some other Functions

enqueue :: Int -> Queue -> Queue
enqueue x Nil = (Ele x Nil)
enqueue x (Ele _ restEles) = reverse (Ele x reverse restEles)
```

I get the error:

> "Couldn't match expected type `Queue' with actual type`[a0]'".

I think that is, because the function doesn't know how to handle my datatype. Am I right here? How can I fix this? Do I have to write my own reverse function? And if could you help me with that, because I am still learning Haskell and don't understand this:

```
reverse = foldl (flip (:)) []
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you have defined a new datatype. Even though it's structurally similar to lists, Haskell will treat it as completely different. So you have to define a new `reverse` function indeed, or alternatively, define a function converting your type into a standard list and back.

But for `enqueue` you do not necessarily need `reverse`. You can just recursively invoke `enqueue` on `restEles` in the case for `Ele` and put the first element back in front of the result.

Here's a pattern for the directly recursive definition for you to complete:

```
enqueue :: Int -> Queue -> Queue
enqueue x Nil                     = Ele x Nil
enqueue x (Ele firstEle restEles) = ...
```

For ..., you have to do what I said above: call `enqueue` recursively on the rest of the
elements and put the first elements back on top.

Comment: Thanks so far! Im learning Haskell in university and the exercise wants it to be runtime efficient and suggests using reverse for O(n). So recursively I also need to tell the last element of the Queue which is the follower I guess.. Just like setting listpointers in C.

Comment: So I got this so far:

`enqueue :: Int -> Queue -> Queue
enqueue x Nil = (Ele x Nil)
enqueue x (Ele _ Nil) = --TELL QUEUE THAT NEXT ELE IS NOT NIL
enqueue x (Ele _ restEles) = enqueue x restEles<`

the problem is what I wrote in the commented line.

Comment: Ok, I've added another hint. You need only two cases, not three. (By the way, if you use your `reverse` approach, you need only *one* case, the separate `Nil` case is then redundant.)

Comment: True.. the first case is just not to waste time. Because when there is no queue I don't need to recurse it 2 times.. Anyway I dont even know if it saves time.. Probably only redundant code as you say..

The problem with your code is that it uses (Ele firstEle restEle), but Queue is defined as (Ele Int Queue).. Or am I just still not getting it?

Comment: Ohh one last time... Im sorry! I completely misread the exercise.. They wanted us to program it with the lists of Haskell so using `type Queue = [Int]` and then it is no problem using reverse.. Thanks anyway for your help, I think I learned something new!

Answer (score 2):

The type of reverse is:

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
```

**Queue** is not a **[a]**.  You need to implement your own **reverseQueue** function that understands your data type.

Answer (score 1):

As for the second part of your question:

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse = foldl (flip (:)) []
```

First, make sure you understand `foldl`. It's a powerful high-order function, which means it can be used to implement a lot of other functions (`sum`,`map`,`filter` and of course `reverse`). You can read about it [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#folds).

Now, let's take a look at a simpler version:

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse xs = foldl (\ys y -> y:ys) [] xs
```

`\ys y -> y:ys` is a very simple function: it takes a list (`ys`) and a value (`y`) and insert the value before the list (`y:ys`). So our course of plan is: start with the empty list (`[]`), insert the first item in `xs` to its left, take the result and insert the second item to its left and so on.

Let's simulate it with a simple list - `[1,2,3]`:

1. We start with the empty list - `[]`
2. Add the first item (`1`) to it's left: `[1]`
3. Add the second item (`2`) to the left of `[1]`: `[2,1]`
4. Add the third item (`3`) to the left of `[2,1]`: `[3,2,1]`

And we've successfully reversed `[1,2,3]`.

Now, `flip` is a function that takes a function and "flips" it's arguments. so if `subtract a b` is `a-b`, then `(flip subtract) a b` is equal to `subtract b a` - `b-a`. So if `(:)` is a function that takes an item `y` and a list `ys` and adds the item to the beginning of the list, then `flip (:)` is the same function with flipped arguments - it takes a list and an item, much like our function - `\ys y -> y:ys`. So we can replace the two of them:

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse xs = foldl (flip (:)) [] xs
```

And now we write in [pointfree](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree) style and eliminate `xs` from both sides of the equation and get the final version:

```
reverse :: [a] -> [a]
reverse = foldl (flip (:)) []
```

Comment: Thanks.. I think I know how fold works, but the rest is much clearer to me now.. At least this one `foldl (\ys y -> y:ys) [] xs` is not so difficult (I just didnt know the \ function) Its hard for me to get how flip can "flip" something without arguments, but a function (:)..

Comment: `\` is not a function - its marks a [lambda expression](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Anonymous_function). As for `flip` - try to play with it in ghci. Create a function of two arguments and see what happens when you flip it. `flip` is one of these Haskell function which is very simple yet very confusing.